# Why does Voorhees call me "china"?

Tags: far-cry-2

In several occasions, [Hector Voorhees](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Hector_Voorhees) will refer to the player as "china". I didn't play as [Xianyong Bai](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Xianyong_Bai) so why would he call me that? Is it a nickname or slang for something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voorhees is South African, has a thick accent and uses a lot of SA slang. [***China/chine*** is SA slang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_South_African_slang_words) for "friend", likely from the [Cockney rhyming slang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyming_slang) "china plate" = "mate":

> *china/chine* – a friend; as in the greeting howzit my china (likely origin: Cockney rhyming slang "China plate" (meaning "my mate"); from early British immigrants.

So it's equivalent to calling you "mate", "bro" or "dude".